# How can I control the converter used for dictionary entries?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I've successfully applied the `JsonConverter` attribute in my classes to govern the converter used for properties of objects in the past. Now, I have a dictionary with several `DateTime` entries which need to be converted in different formats. For example, have a look at the following dictionary:

```
var header = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
     {"Id", reader.GetInt32(0)},
     ...
     {"CreatedAt", reader.GetDateTime(4)},
     ...
     {"StartDate", reader.GetDateTime(7)},
     ...
};
```

When serializing this dictionary, I wish a different format for `CreatedAt` and a different one for `StartDate`. `CreatedAt` should have the full ISO format, e.g. `2014-05-26T09:13:34.56` and `StartDate` should have only the date, e.g. `2014-05-26`.

What is the preferred way of telling Json.NET how to format the entries of a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can do it :

1. Create your own DateOnly class which encaspsulate a DateTime struct.
2. Implements your own type converter by extending `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter` abstract class.

   `public class DateOnly
     {
         public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     }`

**Conveter class**

```
    public class DateOnlyConverter : JsonConverter
   {
      public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    { 
        if (value is DateOnly)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(((DateOnly) value).Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string value = reader.ReadAsString();

        try
        {
            return DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return null; 
        }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (DateOnly); 
    }
}
```

Add your date only class instead of DateTime struct

```
var header = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
 {"Id", reader.GetInt32(0)},
 ...
 {"CreatedAt", reader.GetDateTime(4)},
 ...
 {"StartDate", new DateOnly { Date =  reader.GetDateTime(7)}},
 ...
 };
```

**And finally**

```
string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new IsoDateTimeConverter(), new DateOnlyConverter ());
```

Comment: Good idea! I was hoping that there might be a solution that involved less custom code. If nobody else has an idea, yours will be the one :) Thanks!